# Am I missing something? Error with simple classifier input function in TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning

I've been following along with the freecodecamp tutorial on TensorFlow and I've tried to modify a basic classifier to handle one of my own structured datasets.

I have a training dataset and a testing dataset, each one containing some integers and some strings. I'm trying to predict the value in the *allocated* column, but it keeps throwing this error when the Classifier.train method is called:

```
UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported
     [[{{node head/losses/Cast}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1392                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1393                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1394       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
   1395 
   1396   def _extend_graph(self):

UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported
     [[node head/losses/Cast (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/head/binary_class_head.py:255) ]]
```

I've tried converting the dataset so that all of the values are integers or floats, but I keep getting the same error. From what I've been able to figure out, the classifier should be able to operate on different datatypes, so I can't see why that would be the issue unless I need to define them somewhere?

I know that it's reading in the data correctly, because when I use the .head() function it's all properly formatted. I've been stuck on this error for days and I can't figure out what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is below.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x 

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
from six.moves import urllib
import tensorflow.compat.v2.feature_column as fc
import tensorflow as tf

CSV_COLUMN_NAMES = ['GroupNumber', 'GroupUnit', 'GroupSkill1', 'GroupSkill2', 'GroupSkill3', 'GroupSkill4', 'GroupPreference1', 
                'GroupPreference2', 'GroupPreference3', 'ProjectNumber', 'ProjectUnit', 'ProjectSkill1', 'ProjectSkill2', 'ProjectSkill3', 'ProjectSkill4', 'ProjectPreference1', 'ProjectPreference2', 'ProjectPreference3', 'Allocated']
ALLOCATED = [0, 1]

train = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nickjackson862/machine-learning/main/trainData40_10.csv', names=CSV_COLUMN_NAMES, header=0)
test = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nickjackson862/machine-learning/main/testData40_10.csv', names=CSV_COLUMN_NAMES, header=0)

train_y = train.pop('Allocated')
test_y = test.pop('Allocated')
train.head()


def input_fn(features, labels, training=True, batch_size=100):   
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))    
    if training:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(10).repeat()    
    return dataset.batch(batch_size)

my_feature_columns = []
for key in train.keys():
    my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[50, 20],
    n_classes=2)

classifier.train(
    input_fn=lambda: input_fn(train, train_y, training=True),
    steps=100)

eval_result = classifier.evaluate(
    input_fn=lambda: input_fn(test, test_y, training=False))

print('\nTest set accuracy: {accuracy:0.3f}\n'.format(**eval_result))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in this line where you are creating your feature columns.

`my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))`

You are making every feature a numeric feature, but looking at your dataset several of your fields are strings (that CSV file is public btw, you may want to remedy that).

> I've tried converting the dataset so that all of the values are integers or floats, but I keep getting the same error.

I believe you did this incorrectly. I just tried running your code but with all the string type columns removed and it ran successfully with no errors. All I did was add the following lines after reading in the CSVs

```
train.drop(columns=['GroupSkill1', 'GroupSkill2', 'GroupSkill3', 'GroupSkill4', "ProjectSkill1", "ProjectSkill2", "ProjectSkill3", "ProjectSkill4", ], axis=1, inplace=True)
test.drop(columns=['GroupSkill1', 'GroupSkill2', 'GroupSkill3', 'GroupSkill4', "ProjectSkill1", "ProjectSkill2", "ProjectSkill3", "ProjectSkill4", ], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Check out this article for advice for creating feature columns for your non-numeric data: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. I originally had it set to header=0 but was getting the same error, so I tried header=1 and still the same.

Comment: @NickT I found the actual problem and edited my answer with the solution. I confirmed that your code (with mentioned modification) does run successfully on my machine.